# Код сортирует список кортежей по 2-му элементу. Подскажите, как в функцию b передаётся аргумент el если вызов этой функции без скобок?

Tags: python, функции

```
athletes = [('Дима', 10, 130, 35), ('Тимур', 11, 135, 39), ('Руслан', 9, 140, 33), ('Рустам', 10, 128, 30), ('Амир', 16, 170, 70), ('Рома', 16, 188, 100), ('Матвей', 17, 168, 68), ('Петя', 15, 190, 90)]

def func(num):
    def b(el):  # el - кортеж, элемент списка.
        return el[num]
    return b

num = 1

athletes.sort(key=func(num))

for x in athletes:
    print(*x)
```

Comment: Не совсем понятен вопрос. Пожалуйста, дополните его описанием того, что вы ожидаете от данного кода и в чём конкретно у вас проблема

Comment: "вызов этой функции без скобок" - не вызов функции. `return b` возвращает саму функцию, не её результат её вызова.

Comment: так у вас же функция b описана внутри функции func, вы передали num=1 внутрь функции func. Результатом функции func является функция b.

Comment: Да, return b не вызывает функцию, а возвращает её как объект в функцию key=

Comment: @Франтишек, не забудьте принять помогший вам ответ (если здесь такой есть).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Метод `list.sort()` в аргументе `key` принимает *функцию, которой он передаёт каждый элемент*. А так как ваша функция `func` возвращает функцию, принимающую на вход кортеж и возвращающую элемент из него:

```py
>>> f = func(1)
>>> f(('Дима', 10, 130, 35))
10
```

то всё нормально.

Answer (score 2):

Что-то вы перемудрили, по-моему. Вместо того, чтобы создавать свой аналог функции `itemgetter`, можно передать в параметр `key` лямбду:

```py
>>> athletes = [('Дима', 10, 130, 35), ('Тимур', 11, 135, 39), ('Руслан', 9, 140, 33), ('Рустам', 10, 128, 30), ('Амир', 16, 170, 70), ('Рома', 16, 188, 100), ('Матвей', 17, 168, 68), ('Петя', 15, 190, 90)]
>>> athletes.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
>>> for x in athletes:
        print(*x)

Руслан 9 140 33
Дима 10 130 35
Рустам 10 128 30
Тимур 11 135 39
Петя 15 190 90
Амир 16 170 70
Рома 16 188 100
Матвей 17 168 68
```

Функция `sort` должна принимать в параметр `key` объект-функцию, и вызов этой функции происходит внутри питона, для нас он не виден. Ваша функция возвращает n-ый элемент итерируемого объекта.

P. S. Использовать декораторы там, где они не нужны — плохая идея.